# Difficulty in avoiding empty space when a sub report returns no data to main report

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a a multi level report, meaning I have two sub reports embedded inside a master report.  I have palced one sub report inside a group so that it will run multiple times, once for each group.

Every thing is working fine: sub reports are generated as should be. The actual problem comes when sub report returns nothing: because the sub report is run multiple times, whenever the sub report is empty, the main report is filled with gaps.

Is there any way to avoid that? Can I check whether the dataset is empty, or is there some other solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your sub report's report items like tablix etc embedded inside Rectangle. You would see this behavior.

Comment: I have my sub report inside a table cell. I need to make the visibily of that cell to be false when subreport do not contain any data

Comment: The best thing to do is to reduce the size of the cell, in which you report is embedded in it. This causes no problem because when there is data in the sub report, it is displayed normally independent of size of cell in which the sub report is conatined. If no data is present, it would leave only a small cell space that would be almost negligible.This is what i fallowed. Any more sugesstions are appreciated..thanks..

Comment: what if you hide the complete row hosting your sub-report if there is no data in subreport. You would have to track if there is any data to display in subreport somehow.

Comment: In my case , there is no need at all to display sub report if there is no data beacause my sub report do not contain any headers or so..it just contain some data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in sub-report element `Remove Line When Blank`. Make it `true`.

Comment: I could not find such property on Sub Report. Can you please tell me how can I set this?